# AngularJS Sum values in quantity field base on part number

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an array similar to this:

```
[
{part_number: 1, station: 300, description: "cable", qty: 40},
{part_number: 1, station: 40, description: "cable", qty: 20},
{part_number: 2, station: 300, description: "monitor", qty: 12},
{part_number: 3, station: 40, description: "mounting bracket", qty: 33},
]
```

I am displaying the items with ngRepeat and filtering for unique part number. For each part_number listed, I need to find the qty of each part at the multiple stations and display it in the qty field of that line.

For example:
Part 1 has a total qty of 60, 40 at station 300 and 20 at station 40. Part 2 has a total qty of 12 at station 300. Part 3 has a total qty of 33 at station 40.

I am not sure how to get these quantities or how to display them properly by part number. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT(1):
Sorry to make this so vague which makes it look like I haven't even tried. I have been looking at higher order functions, but cannot determine which ones I should use in conjunction to achieve this end.

Would it be possible to use .map to add a "qty" key/value pair to each object in the array...then simply add an expression in my view to show this value?

I need to get the accumulated quantity of the duplicated parts before I set this value in the uniquely filtered array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through your array and calculate sum. You can try the following

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in result">
  {{item.description}}({{item.part_number}}) - {{item.qty}}
</div>
```

**js**

```
$scope.data = [
      {part_number: 1, station: 300, description: "cable", qty: 40},
      {part_number: 1, station: 40, description: "cable", qty: 20},
      {part_number: 2, station: 300, description: "monitor", qty: 12},
      {part_number: 3, station: 40, description: "mounting bracket", qty: 33}
    ];

$scope.result = []; 
$scope.data.reduce(getSum, {}); 

function getSum(result, item) {
    if (!result[item.part_number]) {
        result[item.part_number] = { part_number: item.part_number, qty: 0 ,description: item.description};
        $scope.result.push(result[item.part_number])
    }
    result[item.part_number].qty += item.qty;
    return result;
}
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mtrR01L0jBwTGXL7HxUn?p=preview)**

Comment: This is perfect for my original question. Thank you very much. I have created a [PLNK](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/iwPsQPS8XTLPJegN) based off of your Demo. I have updated the array with what I am actually receiving from my server. I need just a little more help. I need the "available" key to have a value of NUMBER instead of string. You will notice in the PLNK that it is just adding the strings together instead of a true count.

Comment: @T.O. I'm glad I was able to help. Replace your sum code with the following     result[shopResult.mfc_number].qty += Number(shopResult.available);

Comment: That is absolutely awesome. It works perfectly. Thank you for providing your expertise in this matter.